# How to resolve this "git-upload-pack not found" in Sql Developer

Tags: git, bitbucket, oracle-sqldeveloper, git-clone, git-stash

I'm trying to clone my Bitbucket repository with SQL developer but i am getting the below error.

```
https://username@stash.cit.comp.comg:1234/stash: https://username@stash.cit.comp.comg:1234/stash/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found
```

Comment: It does not look like it is `git-upload-pack not found`, it is `https://username@stash.cit.comp.comg:1234/stash/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found`. I.e. the URI responds with a 404 error code.

Comment: I have modified the URL and given an sample url. But the actual URL works fine in the browser